# Launching an EC-2 Instance for S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm new to web dev and created a site using an S3 bucket that works and is live online. However, I realized that since I'm trying to run a PHP script I found online for a contact form, the site is not truly static so the form will not work. The form is called like this in the html code:

```html
 <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
```

Currently when I try to run this, I get a 405 method not allowed error. Is there a way I can get this code to run? I've done some research online that mentions I have to create an EC2 instance, but I'm overwhelmed by which AMI to choose and don't know how to get the instance connected to the bucket. Can anyone help, or at least does anyone have a resource I could look at to figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/create-dynamic-contact-forms-for-s3-static-websites-using-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-ses/) - ultimately S3 is just an object store and you can't have dynamic content.  But using API Gateway and AWS Lambda allow you to remain "serverless" and still have scalability.  The downside is that your Lambda will have to implemented in something besides PHP - that's not an easily supported language on Lambda.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm gonna have to keep PHP- I used a contact form I found online and I don't know how to write my own

Comment: Then the post below recommending Beanstalk is a good alternative though you really aren't going to be using S3 - all of you PHP code will live on the Beanstalk machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to deploy your PHP app in AWS is using Elastic Beanstalk.

> Elastic Beanstalk for PHP makes it easy to deploy, manage, and scale
> your PHP web applications using Amazon Web Services. Elastic Beanstalk
> for PHP is available to anyone developing or hosting a web application
> using PHP.
>
> Elastic Beanstalk provides configuration options that you can use to
> customize the software that runs on the EC2 instances in your Elastic
> Beanstalk environment. You can configure environment variables needed
> by your application, enable log rotation to Amazon S3, and set common
> PHP initialization settings.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html

Comment: Will this still be compatible with the S3 site I set up?

Comment: It should. Give a try.

Comment: How should I set it up then? I can't find a resource on how to add elastic beanstalk to an existing s3 site.

Comment: Leave your static part in S3, or pack it together with your PHP and deploy everything using Beanstalk.

Comment: So when putting in source code for beanstalk do i put in the entire s3 bucket or just the php document?

Comment: Since you are learning, it will be easier to pack all files and deploy them via Beanstalk.

Comment: Is there a resource you know that I can use to find out how to do that?

Comment: The link I shared in the answer is the official one, from AWS. I recommend you to follow that, and in case you have any issue, submit another question with details.

Comment: I tried it, but I keep getting "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server." errors. What's going wrong????